# How to build instagram bot for android

Tags: python, flutter, automation, bots, instagram

I'm lokking for a way Building an android app which do auto follow, comments, like, and all the process is automatic and like a human.When you Start the app and put your id its open instagram automaticly and start its work until you close instagram

So my question is how can i build like this app? Is it possible on flutter?
I search alot and finde nothing
any idea??

Comment: Hello and welcome! Almost anything is possible given enough resources. That being said, keep in mind, that this is no charity site, and it is unlikely that somebody is just going to build it for you, but if you do have specific questions, please do ask (don't forget to add your code too). An example of such question would be "I am trying to use feature X, but sadly I receive an error Y, here is my code: Z, please help me understand what I am doing wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Kivy` or `KivyMD` if possible. You can use `InstaPy` or build your own API if you feel like being original. Like @jabbson mentioned, I won't provide the full code with working functions because this is not a charity website. However here's a starter code for you:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Interface(Widget):
    pass

class Launcher(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('yourkvfile.kv')

if __name__=='__main__':
    Launcher().run()
```

Good luck in building your app!

Comment: thanks. this is a python code right??

Comment: yeah it is. You should learn kivy if you haven't because you can build GUI apps including mobile apps with kivy. Best wishes to you.